# struct object declaration

Tags: c++, structure

hello every i have made a structure and i want to make 2 objects of it . i am using qtcreator.

i write

`struct grapharray  gao ;`   (grapharray is my structure)

every thig works well but when i write another object like

```
struct grapharray  gao ;
struct grapharray  gao1 ;
```

my program unexpectedly finishes can any one tell me why is it so and where should i declare the struct object

```
struct grapharray
{
int structcol;
double  *structpayloadgraph;

double  *structsessiongraph;

};
```

here is my structure;

and i have a function

```
    struct grapharray graphplotdata(char * filename)
{ // computing some values and returning structure object
}
```

thanks

Comment: We need *way* more information. The code you showed doesn’t cause any problem. The issue is completely unrelated.

Comment: This code is working fine ... Can you show more part of code ?

Comment: sir i have added the information is this enough ?

Comment: How does your `graphplotdata` function populate the two pointers? You return a shallow copy of the structure when you return it. If those pointers are local to the function, then the pointers in the returned structure will be junk, basically.

Comment: sir the code inside the function is working fine with one object. it returns me 2 arrays as well as an int. but when i make an other object the my procram get unexpectedly finish

Comment: Not really, no.  Is there an error, or does the program just finish?  Have you tried stepping through it with a debugger?  Where do you define gao and gao1?  I will say that you don't need to say `struct` in C++ except when actually defining `grapharray`.  `grapharray gao1;` and `grapharray graphplotdata(...)` is sufficient.

Comment: @dennis sir the program just finishes i have gone through code  i.e. its fine with one object but finishes when i declare the other.i have define the two objects inside an event handler of button Sorry sir i didnt get your last point where you are saying you dont need to define struct.........

Comment: Valke below covered my last point.  For the rest, you don't provide enough information to even guess at the problem.  At a minimum, we need the button handler where you define `gao` and `gao1`, with a comment indicating which line you remove and the function works.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well the problem, I would say that you use far too much the "struct" keyword.

If you define your struct as

```
struct grapharray
{
    int structcol;
    double  *structpayloadgraph;
    double  *structsessiongraph;
};
```

then you don't need to use the keyword "struct" when declaring the variables.

```
grapharray  gao;  // without struct keyword
grapharray  gao1; // without struct keyword
```

and your function should be

```
grapharray graphplotdata(char * filename) // without struct once again.
{
    // computing some values and returning structure object
}
```

structs does works almost the same way as classes; the main difference is that structs members and methods are "public" by default and classes members and methods are "private" by default.

---

Edit: Considering the comment of Dennis Zickefoose, this is not the good answer.

Comment: In this case, the extra `struct`s are superfluous, but not dangerous.  They are [were?] necessary in C, so it is allowed in C++ for compatability purposes.  However, they should certainly be removed if you are actually writing in C++, to avoid confusion like this.

Comment: Thank you for the precision, I was persuaded that multiple struct using the same name would cause problems... I should reinvest some time in practicing C time to time on top of C++.